# Change colours on scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Couldn't find an answer to my question.

I have the following code which generates the scatter plot below.

```
scatter_matrix(iris_ds)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, I can't seem to be able to change the colour of the points on the plots, in order to distinguish the data points.

Any suggestions?

Edit: for clarity - there are 3 sets of data points in each scatter plot box. I was wondering if there is a way to:

- Change the colour from blue?
- Change the colours depending on where on the plots the data points appear?

Comment: First and foremost, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Next, you should clarify what points you mean when you say "in order to distinguish the data points.". There are 12 subplots with the scatter points

Comment: Thought I was quite clear, but will clarify.

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html concidentally, the exact same dataset, plotted in multiple colours.

Comment: @warped except I'm using Pandas and Matplotlib

Comment: Please add a MCVE. It's easier to test and answer with it.

Comment: @Clauric just curious, why can't you use `sns`? It fits your need in just one line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [source of pd.plotting.scatter_matrix](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/plotting/_misc.py#L17-L136):

> ```
> def scatter_matrix(frame, alpha=0.5, figsize=None, ax=None,
>                grid=False,
>                diagonal='hist', marker='.', density_kwds=None,
>                hist_kwds=None, range_padding=0.05, **kwds):  # <---
>
>        [...]
>
>             # Deal with the diagonal by drawing a histogram there.
>             if diagonal == 'hist':
>                ax.hist(values, **hist_kwds)   # <---  
>
>
>        [...]
>
>        else:
>            common = (mask[a] & mask[b]).values
>
>            ax.scatter(df[b][common], df[a][common],
>                        marker=marker, alpha=alpha, **kwds) # <---
> ```

you see that the function takes `**kwds` and passes them to `ax.scatter`

so, you can either feed colors directly:

```
colors = iris['species'].replace({'setosa':'red', 'virginica': 'green', 'versicolor':'blue'})   

pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris, c=colors);
```

or you convert the species to numbers, and use a colormap:

```
colors = iris['species'].replace({'setosa':1, 'virginica': 2, 'versicolor':3})

pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris, c=colors, cmap='viridis');
```

further, the function takes `density_kwds` and `hist_kwds` and passes them to `ax.plot` and `ax.hist`, respoectively.
So, you can change the colour of the histograms by passing a dictionary. Ditto for the kdeplots:

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris, hist_kwds={'color':'red'})
```

Comment: Same info in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html?highlight=scatter_matrix#pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix).